# Foundation press dropdown in Wordpress remains open all the time

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, dropdown, zurb-foundation-6, elementor

Having an issue where my Wordpress dropdown built in the appearance menu section remains open in the primary navigation only on desktop; the mobile menu works as expected.

I'm using Foundation press v.6+. Don't think it's a JS issue since the mobile menu is working and i'm not getting any errors in the console. I have no live site link for an example unfortunately and am just working in localhost.

only active plugin is elementor and default wordpress plugins.

[image of what the open drop down looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUNks.png)

Just trying to find a solution to make the dropdown remain closed until clicked. I have been searching for hours and have found no solutions that work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out , top-bar-right , really dislikes flex properties. removing my display:inline-flex attribute solved my issue.

Comment: https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues might be probably also helpful for future issues related to FoundationPress.